# Why useLocalStorage does not work with Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, static-site-generation

This will raise an `Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.` error:

```js
const [selectedOrganizationShortId, setSelectedOrganizationShortId] =
useLocalStorage<string>('teamId', undefined)
```

This will not:

```js
const [selectedOrganizationShortId, setSelectedOrganizationShortId] =
useState<string>(undefined)
const [selectedProgramId, saveSelectedProgramId] = useState<
string | undefined
>(undefined)
```

though both does the same. I would use `useLocalStorage` as it is handy convenience solution, but seems it is not compatible with Next.js.

`useLocalStorage` is used from here: https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-local-storage

Comment: Because `next` runs on the server, but localstorage is only available in the browser

Comment: Is `useLocalStorage` imported from a library? Are you trying to access a value from `localStorage` on the server?  See [Next.js Pre-rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering).

Answer (score 0):

**My answer is a suggestion for your need.**

You could write a custom hook for your purpose so no need to any external libraries:

```js
import { useEffect, useState, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react'

type SetValue<T> = Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>

export default function useLocalStorage<T>(key: string, fallbackValue: T): [T | undefined, SetValue<T | undefined>] {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<T | undefined>();

    useEffect(() => {
        const stored = localStorage.getItem(key);
        setValue(stored ? JSON.parse(stored) : fallbackValue);
    }, [fallbackValue, key]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (value) {
            localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
        }
    }, [key, value]);

    return [value, setValue];
}
```

And then use it like this:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useLocalStorage<string>('key', 'value');
```

Comment: The only problem with you solution, that `fallbackValue` always overwrites the stored value.

Comment: or I have to use with `useMemo` or `useCallback`?

Comment: @János I edited my answer. Please check it.

Comment: now I got a `ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined` error

Comment: @János Sorry, I forgot that you're using Next.JS. I edited my answer again. It should work now.

Comment: It is still not good, new value of `fallbackValue` always overwrites the old when navigating back and forth in the app. In my case `fallbackValue` can change. But once value is written to local storage, I would retain it.

Comment: Would you look at my answer, I made it based on your first version

Comment: Yes sure. I think I had a misunderstanding with your question.

Comment: @János I couldn't edit your answer. But edited my answer based on your result with some improvements.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```js
import { useEffect, useState, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react'

type SetValue<T> = Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>

export default function useLocalStorage<T>(
    key: string,
    fallbackValue: T
): [T, SetValue<T>] {
    const [value, setValue] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
        const stored = localStorage.getItem(key)
        if (!stored) {
            return
        }
        setValue(stored ? JSON.parse(stored) : fallbackValue)
    }, [fallbackValue, key])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!value) {
            return
        }
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
    }, [key, value])

    return [value, setValue]
}
```

And calling like this:

```js
const [selectedOrganizationShortId, setSelectedOrganizationShortId] =
        useLocalStorage<string>(
            'teamId',
            auth.userDTO?.organizations
                ? Object.keys(auth.userDTO?.organizations)[0]
                : ''
```

Comment: In your code, fallbackValue is never set to localstorage.